# Problema al hacer deploy con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, digitalocean, lampp

Estoy tratando de hacer deploy a mi aplicacion creada con laravel, pero al tratarlo de subir a mi VPS en `DigitalOcean`, no se muestra nada lo pueden observar en `www.d-supplier.com` no se que archivos necesiten para que me ayuden a resolver mi problema pero en `/var/www` se encuentra la carpeta de mi proyecto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en en archivo `nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

lo tengo de la siguiente manera [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en la pagina no se muestra nada ja, todo esta en blanco :( estoy usando `laravel 5.6` y `php 7` y en `DigitalOcean` estoy usando Ubuntu `LAMP en 16.04`

> Error de log de Laravel
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: revisa el log de laravel en `app/storage/logs/` y el de apache por defecto `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, la pagina esta retornando un error 500

Comment: Estás usando base de datos? si es así revisa la configuración del archivo .env

Comment: @milo ya configure bien el archivo .env para que se conecte a la base de datos con sus respectivos datos e incluso genere la clave que debe tener en dicho archivo pero no lo he conseguido

Comment: @Xerifacavo de revisar el log de laravel y me arroja el error que aparece en la imagen que acabo de añadir

Comment: @cesg.dav Te está tirando un error de sintaxis, seguramente porque usas los comparadores "??" y no tienes la versión adecuada de php, mirate este link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992685/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-helpers-php-233

Comment: @RaúlMonge estuve leyendo la liga que me compartiste en tu comentario, pero dice que lo soluciono actualizando el PHP, el cual ya lo tengo actualizado al 7.2